# active admin gem error message just following the instructions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am using `ruby 3.1.3`, `rails 7.0.5` and `activeadmin 3.0`.

I just followed the installation instructions from the [activeadmin website](https://activeadmin.info/0-installation.html), but I got the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Ransack needs AdminUser attributes explicitly allowlisted as
searchable. Define a `ransackable_attributes` class method in your `AdminUser`
model, watching out for items you DON'T want searchable (for
example, `encrypted_password`, `password_reset_token`, `owner` or
other sensitive information). You can use the following as a base:

ruby
class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord

  # ...

  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    ["created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "id", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "updated_at"]
  end

  # ...

end

):
    1: # frozen_string_literal: true
    2: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
```

I tried to follow the instructions but I got the same error but now the array inside of the function is empty.

Comment: Can you post the source of your ```app/admin/admin_users.rb``` file and your admin_user.rb model? It is hard to offer assistance with a sparse context.

Comment: Yes, I'm having the same issue, not only with `admin_users`, but with all my models, only the dashboard page is working in active admin, it was working before, could be a bug in `active_admin` gem?

Answer (score 3):

Just went through the same issue while upgrading from active_admin 2.x to 3.0.

The new version uses a new version of ransack (v4) that includes a breaking change as it now requires you to explicitly declare an allowed list of attributes and associations in your models for searching against (changelog [here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/releases/tag/v4.0.0)).

Whitelisting all attributes at your `ApplicationRecord` model will get your app running again:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    authorizable_ransackable_attributes
  end

  def self.ransackable_associations(auth_object = nil)
    authorizable_ransackable_associations
  end
end
```

But you might want to customize these lists for each specific model on your codebase.